# a random distribution of RA&Dec

Tags: coordinate

How to make random positions in Equatorial coordinate system?

If I divide Dec between -90 and 90 evenly, the space distribution is not random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your problem is that you have a sphere. To compensate for the polar declination skew, you just calculate $$\sin^{-1}(\mathtt{rand})$$
Where $\mathtt{rand}$ is a number in an evenly divided -1 to 1 range. Alternatively, you can use another trigonometric function based on what you have available, but you get the idea.

RA can obviously be divided evenly.

Comment: beautiful math  :)

Comment: @hohmannfan  You mean I need to make random Decs, then change them to sin-1(dec)? or sin-1(dec) is a weighing coefficient which correlates with area?

Comment: @questionhang You need to make random numbers evenly in the -1 to 1 area, and pipe them through the sin-1 formula. The output can be used together with random RA's to get random coordinates on a sphere, without any skew.

Comment: @@hohmannfan I do not understand my question now. What is a random distribution on a 2-D sphere?